# AWS CLI: Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Was able to set up a pull from an S3 bucket on a Mac seamlessly, but have been struggling with an identical process on a PC (Windows). Here is what I have done -- any help along the way would be much appreciated.

1. Installed `awscli` using `pip`
2. Ran `aws configure` in the command prompt and inputed the proper access key id and secret access key.
3. Ran the s3 code: `G:\>aws s3 cp --recursive s3://url-index-given/ .` (where the url was replaced with `url-index-given` for example purposes).

And got this error:
`fatal error: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://url-index-given.s3.None.amazonaws.com/?list-type=2&prefix=&encoding-type=url"`

I have tried uninstalling the `awscli` package and followed [this process](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-could-not-connect-endpoint-url/) recommended by Amazon without any errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error indicates have you have given an invalid value for `Region` when using `aws configure`. (See the `None` in the URL? That is where the Region normally goes.)

You should run `aws configure` again and give it a valid region (eg `us-west-2`).

Comment: Interesting. I had "us-east1" in the file and I swear it used to work. Now I had to update to "us-east-1" to make it work.